# Why does a single vanilla DataFrame.count() cause 2 jobs to be executed by pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to understand how spark transforms the logical execution plan to a physical execution plan

I do 2 things:

1. read a csv file
2. count over the dataframe

So I was expecting 2 jobs only to be executed by the DAG

Why is this creating 3 jobs total?
[image]

and why did it need 3 different stages for this?
[image]

Comment: It might be that one stage is used for schema inferring, could you try the same but with explicitly providing the schema while reading?

Comment: Robert, thanks for your reply. inferSchema is false by default, that's why I skipped it. Following your advice, I did add the ".option("inferSchema", "false")  " but I got the same result. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I even went as far as removing the header from the file, and forcing inferSchema to disable, still 3 jobs:
[image]